# Powershell ISE crashes often when using XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell

I often find XAML in the code crashes the program when I run it using Powershell v4 ISE on Windows 7 64.

I does not seem to matter how short or complex the script is or how the program is structured; if using XAML in the script or calling in an external script, loading or parsing XML and XAML with the nodereader, all performs the same.

Run the script and randomly the ISE crashes and reopens.

Thankfully running outside of the ISE in Single Thread Appartment it is always fine. 
Seems the most stable method I have found is open a single script use a single tab, remove the PresentationCore and PresentationFramework references (oddly)

Comment: Do you have some hint on the failing assembly in the application event log?

Comment: FYI--this may be helpful: https://gist.github.com/altrive/6227237.  Was seeing a ton of crashing until I implemented the workaround...and go figure, MS closed the bug report without a fix!

Comment: Thanks ***slashp*** nice tip. I figured in the end that it was a bug within the ISE that would probably take a redesign to fix, starting of a new thread with the dispatcher makes perfect sense, I look forward to trying it out

Comment: The workaround at gist.github.com/altrive/6227237 worked perfectly fine for me!  Can't believe I didn't look for this information sooner.